# Solving a PDE arising from physics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, quantum-mechanics

Is there a way to find an analytic solution to the following PDE?

$i \partial _t \psi = - \gamma \partial _x ^2 \psi - c x $cos$(\omega t) \psi $,

where $\psi (x,t)$ is defined (in $x$) on the interval $[0,L]$, and $\psi (0,t) = \psi (L,t) = 0 $.

Comment: Do you know how the solution will look like for $\omega=0$?

Comment: Maybe try solving it in momentum space instead. At least then you'll just have a first order differential equation.

Comment: @O.L. No. Perhaps doing a Laplace transform in $t$ will result in an ODE that is not too hard to solve?

Comment: @Spencer I'm sorry, what does it mean to solve in momentum space?

Comment: To daunpunk:  will an infinite series developed from time-dependent perturbation theory count as " analytic"?

Comment: @O.L. Ah, I think if $\gamma = 0$, you can do a two-sided Laplace transform to get an ODE that looks similar to the Airy/Stokes equation, but with complex coefficients. I don't know if that is easy to solve.

Comment: @RobertLewis, I'll take whatever I can get! Of course, I'd like a solution that is as "nice" as possible.

Comment: To get the equation in momentum space make the substitution $ \hat{x} = \frac{\hbar}{i}\partial_p$ and $\hat{p}-> p$. In this case instead of your momentum becoming a derivative your position variable is. It essential exchanges the traditional roles of $x$ and $p$.

Comment: @Spencer So, just doing a Fourier transform in $x$?

Comment: @daunpunk thats right

Comment: I mention that method because this problem can be solved that way in the case $\omega=0$. You solve for the energy eigenstates and then construct the propagator. Out out curiosity what is your background (Physics/Mathematics)?

Comment: @Spencer, I'm a math grad student working in quantum algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for the case of $\gamma,c,\omega\neq0$ :

Let $\psi=e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u$ ,

Then $\partial_t\psi=\partial_t\left(e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u\right)=e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_tu+icx\cos(\omega t)e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u$

$\partial_x\psi=\partial_x\left(e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u\right)=e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_xu+\dfrac{ic\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u$

$\partial_x^2\psi=\partial_x\left(e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_xu+\dfrac{ic\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u\right)=e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_x^2u+\dfrac{ic\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_xu+\dfrac{ic\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_xu+\left(\dfrac{ic\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)^2e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u=e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_x^2u+\dfrac{2ic\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_xu-\dfrac{c^2\sin^2(\omega t)}{\omega^2}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u$

$\therefore i\left(e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_tu+icx\cos(\omega t)e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u\right)=-\gamma\left(e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_x^2u+\dfrac{2ic\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_xu-\dfrac{c^2\sin^2(\omega t)}{\omega^2}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u\right)-cx\cos(\omega t)e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u$

$ie^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_tu-cx\cos(\omega t)e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u=-\gamma e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_x^2u-\dfrac{2ic\gamma\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_xu+\dfrac{c^2\gamma\sin^2(\omega t)}{\omega^2}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u-cx\cos(\omega t)e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u$

$ie^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_tu=-\gamma e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_x^2u-\dfrac{2ic\gamma\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}\partial_xu+\dfrac{c^2\gamma\sin^2(\omega t)}{\omega^2}e^{\frac{icx\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}}u$

$\partial_tu=i\gamma\partial_x^2u-\dfrac{2c\gamma\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\partial_xu-\dfrac{ic^2\gamma\sin^2(\omega t)}{\omega^2}u$

Let $\begin{cases}v=x+\dfrac{2c\gamma\cos(\omega t)}{\omega^2}\\w=t\end{cases}$ ,

Then $\partial_tu=\partial_vu\partial_tv+\partial_wu\partial_tw=-\dfrac{2c\gamma\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\partial_vu+\partial_wu$

$\partial_xu=\partial_vu\partial_xv+\partial_wu\partial_xw=\partial_vu$

$\partial_x^2u=\partial_x(\partial_vu)=\partial_v(\partial_vu)\partial_xv+\partial_w(\partial_vu)\partial_xw=\partial_v^2u$

$\therefore-\dfrac{2c\gamma\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\partial_vu+\partial_wu=i\gamma\partial_v^2u-\dfrac{2c\gamma\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\partial_vu-\dfrac{ic^2\gamma\sin^2(\omega w)}{\omega^2}u$

$\partial_wu=i\gamma\partial_v^2u-\dfrac{ic^2\gamma\sin^2(\omega w)}{\omega^2}u$

Which is separable.